# How to test linear independence of boolean array in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, independent-set

The rows of this matrix are *not* linearly independent, as the first two rows can be added (or XORed) to produce the third:

```
matrix = [
    [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 1, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
]
```

One could do brute-force reduction of the rows, with deeply nested *for* loops and *if* conditions and testing for an all zero row, but the resulting code doesn't feel like python.

Without using *numpy* or other library, what is a pythonic way of testing for independent rows (on much larger matrices)?

Comment: How much "much larger" matrices?

Comment: Do you have proof that XOR is correct?

Comment: @KellyBundy "much larger" could be in the hundreds.

Comment: The [definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearlyIndependent.html) uses multiplication and addition, nor XOR...

Comment: @KellyBundy,  Aren't XOR and ADD the same for booleans?
0+0=0=0^0,
0+1=1=0^1,
1+0=1=1^0,
1+1=0=1^1.

Comment: The question says nothing about booleans. It does say "binary array", but that just refers to the input. If you add the rows, you get [3,1,2,3], not [1,1,0,1].

Comment: @KellyBundy, I've now changed "binary" to "boolean" to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Ok. I btw tried a bit to find a counter-example, i.e., where xor and addition disagree, and didn't find one. Maybe they are even equivalent, although I doubt it.

Comment: @KellyBundy, there are only the four cases to test for agreement, as in my comment.

Comment: But that's just for adding/xoring *two* rows, and only considering factors 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
import itertools

def linearly_independent (rows):
    for r in range(2, len(rows) + 1):
        for c in itertools.combinations(rows, r):
            x = [0 for x in c[0]]
            for row in c:
                for i in range(len(x)):
                    x[i] ^= row[i]
            if not 1 in x:
                return False
    return True
```

If so, then calling algorithmically terrible code like this "Pythonic" and row reduction "brute force" suggests that your aesthetic principles are a problem.  Because row reduction is absolutely the right approach.

---

For comparison here is the row reduction solution.

```
def linearly_independent (rows):
    # Clone everything to not mess up the original.
    rows = [[x for x in r] for r in rows]

    # We will be accessing rows[i][j].
    # Start at the top corner.
    i = j = 0
    while j < len(rows[0]):
        if 1 != rows[i][j]:
            found = False
            for i_swap in range(i+1, len(rows)):
                if 1 == rows[i_swap][j]:
                    (rows[i], rows[i_swap]) = (rows[i_swap], rows[i])
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found:
                j += 1
                continue
        # Now we have a row with a leading 1.
        for i_other in range(i+1, len(rows)):
            if rows[i_other][j] == 1:
                for k in range(j, len(rows[0])):
                    rows[i_other][k] ^= rows[i][k]
        i += 1
        if len(rows) < i:
            return True

    return False
```

Algorithmically the combinations code for an `n x m` matrix scales like `O(m * n * 2^n)`.  Row reduction scales like `O(m * n^2)`.  Which is much better.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a self-contained solution, "Without using numpy or other library".

Comment: @RayButterworth Usually when people say "Pythonic", the Python standard library is fair game. Anyways I added a pure Python solution for row reduction with no libraries at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is also brute force, but using some Python tools:

```
from itertools import combinations

matrix = [
    [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 1, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
]

row_combinations = combinations(matrix, 2)


linear_dependant = True

for combination in row_combinations:
    
    result = [i1 ^ i2 for i1, i2 in zip(combination[0], combination[1])]
    not_all_zeros = not all([elem == 0 for elem in result])

    if not_all_zeros:
        linear_dependant = False
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a self-contained solution, "Without using numpy or other library".

Comment: Itertools is a built-in python module, you won't need to install any third-party library. You can use both solutions out-of-the-box.